# Design classes for "two-dimension"-like expansion by inheritance

Tags: c++, oop

I'd like to make two base classes (e.g. figure and move) with some children for each one(cube, sphere and so on for figure; shift, rotate, rescale and so on for moves). Initial number of figures and moves is unknown - it must be expandable. Each move should know how to move each figure, so having N figures and M moves means to have N*M function for them. (Adding a move requires creation of N functions for each already existing figure and adding figure requires creation of M functions for each already existing move).

The question is how to declare theese functions? For example, I'll have a class Set containing list of figures (aka vector) and I need to ask this class to move all the figures by i-th move. Probably set would have a method of

```
set::move_all (const move& )
```

and... well what next? The easiest idea is to create virtual method

```
class figure { 
    ...
    virtual void move_this (const move& ) 
    ...
}
```

to call a virtual method move_figure

```
class figure_i: public figure {
    ...    
    virtual void move_this (const move& M)
       {M.move_figure(*this);
       }  
    ... 
}

class move {
    ...
    template <class T> virtual void move_figure (T&) const
    ...
}
```

and specialize it for each i-th move like this

```
template <> void shift::move_figure <cube> (cube& C)
    {
    }
```

and so on, but virtual templates are illegal.

Comment: Well, idk.. but what the alternative?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and drop all your codebase, read some design/conception books, and restart from scratch

Comment: "Aurélien Vallée" comment is right, maybe a little harsh, but you may want to rethink your problem. Anyway, your problem is related to templates, and many template designs can be switched to subclassing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my current solution is to use typeid/typeinfo to identify figure/move pair and call corresponding function (non-member) to move figure by this move from global object of map type like this

```
typedef pair<string, string> fm_pair_t;
typedef figure (*fm_act_f) (const figure& F, const move& M);
map<fm_pair_r, fm_act_f> global_fm_map;

class move {
   ...
   figure move_figure (const figure& F) const
     {map<fm_pair_r, fm_act_f>::const_iterator i = 
          global_fm_map.find (fm_pair_t(typeid(F).name(), typeid(*this).name()));
      if (i == global_fm_map.end()) return F;
      return i->second (F, *this);
     }
   ...
};
```

and somewhere

```
figure cube_shift (const figure& _F, const move& _M)
   {const cube& F = *dynamic_cast <const cube*> (&F);
    const shift& M = *dynamic_cast <const shift*> (&M);

    // act here with F and M like normal instances of cube and shift!

   };
```

and, of course

```
global_fm_map(typeid(cube).name(), typeid(shift).name()) = cube_shift;
```

so unlike case of using templates, everything is independent and well expandable.

Comment: This requires you to write out the full N*M functions no matter what though, andand's solution requires only M functions, with the possibility of specializations if required.

Comment: In fact I do need to write most of N*M functions and this is what I was asking for. The main problem was how to add M+1-th figure or N+1-th move without touching declaration and implementation of N and M previous. And in my solution is still a place for "default" case - if required function not registered figure is not changed.

Comment: Since you're selecting the function by type, the dynamic_cast is not needed, you can use a normal pointer cast.  Also this code could be vastly improved speed-and-size-wise if you gave each figure/move class a unique `const static unsigned int ID = /*?*/` and `virtual unsigned int getID() const {return ID;}`, and replaced the `map<pair<string,string>, fm_act_f>` with a `unordered_map<pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, fm_act_f>`  Then it won't do string comparisons, won't do log(n) lookups, and doesn't require RTTI.

Comment: Yup, you're right here. Just if once a blue moon figures and moves are be added to this program by many people it would be hard to avoid using same unsigned int ID by them... strings give more degree of freedom, IMHO.

Comment: There are ways around that: http://arcticinteractive.com/2009/04/18/compile-time-string-hashing-boost-mpl/  `meta::hash_cstring< mpl::string<'squa','re'> >::value`

Answer (score 1):

You are making things more complicated than needed.  You have a collection of objects (which you are calling `figures`) and a collection of actions (which you are calling `moves`).  The obvious choice from an OOP perspective is to make the `moves` methods in your `figures` classes.

**Update**

Based on the comment below, you should be using a linear algebra library such as [`boost::ublas`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm).  There are others as well that you might want to look into such as [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) (more or less shown below).

The basic idea is to abstract both the figures and the moves to generalize both so you don't have to rewrite the code for each possible combination.  Thus, you would create a base class which looks something like:

```
template <typename T> class figure
{
    std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d<T> > point_list;
    ...

    void applyTransform(const Eigen::Affine3d<T>& src)
    {
       for (auto pt=point_list.begin(); pt != point_list.end(); pt++)
           (*pt) = src * (*pt);
    }
}
```

In this case, you define your point list based on the shape you are rendering.  You can adjust meaning of the points in your derived classes to define specific geometric figures you're interested in.  The `Eigen::Affine3D` class is used to define the transformations you want to apply.  Eigen already has rotations and other affine transformations defined, so you should be able to reuse those.

You can also look into some specialized OpenGL or DirectX geometry classes which does all of this for you.

Comment: But this way I'll to touch figure base (and existing figure child classes) class each time I add new move. (And, well, movies should move not only figures.)

Comment: @Nick: You're going to have to write that code anyway; you just have to decide where it makes sense to put it. BTW, what's the overall purpose of the project? Usually when people start talking about moving figures, my mind immediately jumps to affine transformation and modeling things in some vector space. If that's the case, you're probably better off using a simplified linear algebra / computer graphics library to manage these movements.

Comment: yup, you are almost right here. It is modeling of sets of point distribution in space and plane (maybe in R^n in future). The program is to create, transform (move) them, project them to or section by plane and cut by border (border is intersection of border primitives) - at user level. So I need code to calculate what happens to border when moving, projecting to plane and so on. Indeed, the questing is where to put the code bearing in mind that I'm (or someone else) going to add new borders and new moves in future...

Comment: @Nick:  See update.  Disclaimer:  I wrote most of that from memory and didn't try compiling it, so your code will likely look a little different.

Comment: Well, a lot of things to think about and to learn... thanks you.

Comment: @Nick: `I'll [have] to touch ... existing figure child classes` not always.  The applyTransform he coded can move or rotate any shape.  You _don't_ have to copy that for each shape, and only minor modification for each move. `movies should move not only figures.` wait, what else would a move act upon?